# Is it possible to generate bbl file without compiling a pdf?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, auxiliary-files

Suppose that we have a `refs.bib` file containing bibtex entries, and that we would like to use the `plainnat` as the style.

I would like to generate a `bbl` file **without** the necessicity to compile a PDF file. I think this would be particularlly usefuly for software that parse and print bibtex entries, say, e.g., bib->html.

The first thought is to use command `bibtex` but this requires a `aux` file which essentially needs to compile a pdf.

Comment: well you could create a suitable aux-file manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bibtex needs only three things from the aux-file:

a command telling it which style to use, commands telling it which bib-files to use and commands telling it which entries to use. So if you create a aux-file  with this content

```
\bibstyle{plainnat}
\citation{doody}
\bibdata{biblatex-examples}
```

and then run bibtex on it you will get the same bbl  you would get if latex had created such an aux-file.

Comment: This works indeed!